# How to Use Text in Unity3d

Tags: unity, text

How Can i Create Text in Unity3D?
I Use "3D Text" But Its Always on Top Of Everything!
Can You Suggest Anything?
I creating a 2D Game So its not Necessarily a 3D Text..

Edit: Because I Building a 2D Game My Scene is Full of Planes in Front of Camera And I want My Text to be Over One of the Planes and when plane is moving My Text appears behind it.
But When I Use "3D Text" Its Always In Front of Everything.

Sorry for My Bad English...

Comment: How are you wanting the text to be? If you don't want it to be on top of everything, how do you want it? Please edit your question to tell us exactly what you want to do.

Comment: ok I Edit The Question. Tnx For Reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use [this shader](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=3DText) to achieve the effect you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a polygon with the texture of your text.

Are you using 2D Toolkit or something similar? This makes the process super easy and you can layer the text however you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to use a secondary camera to render your airplanes, and use the main camera to render everything that has to be below the airplanes (such as text).

Add a new camera, adjust its depth to a value greater than your main camera. Make sure its `normalized view port rect` property has the values `X:0 Y:0 W:1 H:1` (to take the whole screen). Make sure it's set to ignore all layers except for the airplanes' layer (see the `Culling Mask` property). Also change your main camera so that it ignores the airplanes' layer (but doesn't ignore the rest).

Now the text will be rendered by the main camera, and the airplanes will be rendered by the secondary camera. The text will appear below the airplanes.

To make the text appear on top of the airplanes, use the 2nd camera to render text, and the first camera to render the airplanes.